# Android getAssets in Common class gives "The method getAsssets() is undefined for the type Context" error

Tags: android, typeface

I have a class named CommonCode that is used for stocking all methods I frequently need.

One of those methods is creating a toast with a custom layout. I want to give the TextView in that toast a custom font so I use a TypeFace.
When trying to get the custom font from my assets folder, it goes wrong.

I get the issue "The method getAsssets() is undefined for the type Context".

Here's my code:
the CommonCode class

```
public class CommonCode {

public static void showToast(String toastString, Context context, View view) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_layout, (ViewGroup) view);

    ImageView image = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.toastImage);
    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.android);

    TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.toastText);

    Typeface type = Typeface.createFromFile(context.getAsssets(), "fonts/aircruiser.ttf"); 

    text.setTypeface(type);
    text.setText(toastString);

    Toast toast = new Toast(context);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
    toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.setView(layout);
    toast.show(); 
}

}
```

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `getAssets()` instead of `getAsssets(),` :

```
Typeface type= Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/aircruiser.ttf");  
text.setTypeface(type);
```