# Custom Text For Dialog implements OnClick Listener Android

Tags: android

Friends I just Wanna set Custom Typeface Form my assets/fonts folder 
My Java Code Looks like this

```
package customtext;
import android.app.Dialog;  
import android.content.Context;  
import android.os.Bundle;  
import android.view.View;  
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
public class Custom extends Dialog implements android.view.View.OnClickListener{  
    public Custom(Context context) {  
        super(context);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
}  
Button btn;  
    @Override  
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
        setContentView(R.layout.custom);  
        btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.dismis_dialog);  
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);  
    }  
    @Override  
    public void onClick(View v) {  
        dismiss();  
    }  
}
```

When I try to add like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10061494/android-getassets-in-common-class-gives-the-method-getasssets-is-undefined-fo)  Its not worked for me

its giving error

here this is my XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"   
   android:orientation="vertical"
   style="@style/Theme.CustomDialog"   >

       <FrameLayout
           android:layout_width="250sp"
           android:layout_height="70sp"
           android:background="#ee8f03" >
            <TextView
                 android:layout_width="180sp"  
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
                 android:id="@+id/sharedialog"
                 android:text="@string/msg"  
                 android:textColor="#272b2d"
                 android:background="#ef8e01"
                 android:layout_gravity="center" >  
            </TextView>  
       </FrameLayout>

       <FrameLayout
           android:layout_width="250sp"
           android:layout_height="70sp"
           android:background="#fff" >

           <Button 
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
             android:layout_gravity="bottom"
             android:clickable="true" 
             android:id="@+id/dismis_dialog"  
             android:text="@string/dismis"/> 
       </FrameLayout>

  </LinearLayout>
```

Would you please tell how to add custom font to this type of context Dialog Box

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out this links for creating Custom Dialog

http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/

also you can set the custom font like this way

```
Typeface type = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets()/fonts, "myfonts.ttc");
youTextView.setTypeface(type);
```

put your fonts into fonts folder under assets dir

Comment: If you accessing asset folder in non-activity class then you need context object like context.getAssets() through this you can use it

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Typeface type = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "name.ttc");
dismis_dialog.setTypeface(type);
sharedialog.setTypeface(type);
```